# What is the reason a FROM-subquery is not visible in the WHERE-subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id
FROM (SELECT  * FROM Grades WHERE dept_id = 'MT') T
WHERE grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM T);
```

Oracle complains that `T` in the subquery in WHERE is not an existing table. I know that I can easily work around this by using `WITH`, but still I want to understand. What is the rule of SQL that governs this case and the logic behind that rule?

Comment: T is just a label, not a result. Use a CTE instead.

Comment: @jarlh Let it be a label. Why should such a label be in scope in `WHERE`, but not in the subquery in `WHERE`? I would expect names in the outer scope to be accessible in the inner scope...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The query is operating on the subquery you have aliased as `T`.  So in the `WHERE` clause, you would be asking the database to perform another, different query on the same subquery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how the reason matters; It is, and knowing why won't change that.

As SQL is declarative, there are rules about scope, order of execution, order of precedence, etc.  Rules that enable the cost based planner to generate the plan that will actually be executed.  One such rule is that you can't evaluate two independent queries over the same set.  Even if `T` was a material table, referencing it twice would bring it in the plan as two independent sets.

Instead you need a different way to express your requirement that's more in keeping with the language.  One where you don't try to parse the same set multiple times.

For example, you can acquire two ***sets*** from the same ***expression*** in this manner...

```
WITH
  T AS
(
  SELECT * FROM Grades WHERE dept_id = 'MT'
)
SELECT DISTINCT student_id
FROM T
WHERE grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM T);
```

Or, you could use windowed functions and allow the internal engine to determine how best to evaluate all the terms with minimum cost...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Grades.*,
    MAX(grade) OVER ()   AS max_grade
  FROM
    Grades
  WHERE
    dept_id = 'MT'
)
  T
WHERE
  grade = max_grade
```

***VERY LONG EDIT:*** Subjective and Objective arguments against the proposal

The suggestion is that sets defined in outer queries are usable as independent sets in inner queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  student_id
FROM
(
  SELECT  * FROM Grades WHERE dept_id = 'MT'
)
  newSetDefinition
WHERE
  grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM newSetDefinition)

-----------------------------
Functionally Equivalent To...
-----------------------------

WITH
  newSetDefinition
AS
(
  SELECT  * FROM Grades WHERE dept_id = 'MT'
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  student_id
FROM
  newSetDefinition
WHERE
  grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM newSetDefinition)
```

This implies that the following should also work...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  newSetDefinition.student_id
FROM
(
  SELECT  * FROM Grades WHERE dept_id = 'MT'
)
  newSetDefinition
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(grade) AS maxGrade FROM newSetDefinition
)
  newSetSummary
    ON newSetSummary.maxGrade = newSetDefinition.grade

-----------------------------
Functionally Equivalent To...
-----------------------------

WITH
  newSetDefinition
AS
(
  SELECT  * FROM Grades WHERE dept_id = 'MT'
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  newSetDefinition.student_id
FROM
  newSetDefinition
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(grade) AS maxGrade FROM newSetDefinition
)
  newSetSummary
    ON newSetSummary.maxGrade = newSetDefinition.grade
```

So far, so good...

With nested queries it become a little hazier, as the following isn't possible to accurately represent with CTEs due to different scope availability and naming collisions.  It becomes necessary to define CTEs inside sub-queries...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 1
)
  smeg
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE somethingElse = 2
  )
    smeg
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS maxID FROM smeg
  )
    smegSummary
      ON smegSummary.maxID = smeg.ID
)
  smegSubSet
    ON smegSubSet.parentID = smeg.ID

-----------------------------
Functionally Equivalent To...
-----------------------------

WITH
   smeg AS
(
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  smeg
INNER JOIN
(
  WITH
    smeg AS
  (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 1
  )
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    smeg
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS maxID FROM smeg
  )
    smegSummary
      ON smegSummary.maxID = smeg.ID
)
  smegSubSet
    ON smegSubSet.parentID = smeg.ID
```

Okay, so that's okay, just a bit untidy.  CTEs help avoid needing deep nesting, so having nested syntax for CTEs is "messy", but even that's a subjective measure.

When you see a "set reference" you look to outer queries until you find a set with that alias, and if none are found use normal rules; CTES, then tables/views in the current schema, then tables/views in the current database but different schema, all taking into account permissions, etc.

Fine, fairly standard scoping rules.

But this next scenario is more objectively problematic...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM smeg WHERE something = 1
)
  smeg
```

In current ANSI-SQL this is fine, provided there is a table with the name `smeg`.

In AlwaysLearning-SQL it's a circular reference.  The "nearest" definition for `smeg` is the outer query.  That "overrides" any tables or views named `smeg`.  So, the inner query is now selecting from...itself...

There's an argument to say "just let it raise a circular reference error then".

**But that breaks backward-compatibility.**

Imagine if Oracle added this functionality to v13?  All of a sudden queries that used to work start raising circular reference errors?  Why?  To make some sub-queries work like CTEs, under the presumption that doing so is helpful/convenient?  `To make some aspects of life "convenient" we broke some of your queries.`

Breaking backwards compatibility happens.  But only when the gains ***far*** outweigh the consequences.

In this case ***anything*** that can be done with your suggestion can be done with CTEs.  And CTEs were added without breaking any legacy behaviours.  And *(subjectively/arguably)* CTEs can do this in a manner that is more structured, more maintainable, simpler to read, easier to debug, etc.

I'm personally very happy that no-one has yet broken some queries to implement some very niche functionality.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. However, I am still curious what benefits this rule buys. Can this particular query be executed faster because of this rule?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - You're thinking Impertively.  SQL isn't Imperative, it's Declarative : SQL isn't a program, it's a problem notation.  The underlying planner turns that in to a program *(a Plan)*, and it may or may not be anything like you expect.  Using `MAX(grade) OVER ()` may or may not require a scan and join to evaluate, depending on available indexes, etc.  The structure and rules of `SQL` are not to allow you control over the planning, it's to allow you concise and robust expression of relational operations, and to allow the planner to easily parse and plan a solution.

Comment: Do you mean that I cannot appreciate this (annoying to be honest) limitation without deeply understanding the workings of the planner of the particular DBMS?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - No, I said that the syntax is formed to allow standarised ***expression*** of relational operations *(declarative)*, not to stipulate specific actions to be followed explicitly *(imperative)*.  Research the two language forms.  By being declarative there is ***NOTHING*** in the language that prevents the planner from re-using results where suitable *(allowing for memory allocation, join algorithms, indexes, statistics, costs, etc, etc)*.  Just because you wrote it twice doesn't mean it executes twice, just because you wrote it once doesn't mean it only executes once.

Comment: I think that I understand the difference between *imperative* and *declarative*. The thing I don't and am trying to understand is: why limit the expressive freedom of the programmer by not letting him use `T` once again in the `WHERE`-subquery? The planner could easily translate that query into one that uses CTE.

Comment: Subjectively; because there is already a "better" way. CTE notation bring cleaner, more explicit, and overall more maintainable.

Comment: Objectively; because it breaks backwards compatibility. This is legal; `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t) AS t`, but would introduce a circular reference in your scheme. Any DBMS that upgraded to your suggested 'feature' would then break certain queries.  Breaking backwards compatibility happens, but only when the benefits are huge.

Comment: I failed to understand the last comment (the objective one). But it is this comment that seems to begin to answer the second part of the original question. It would be great if you could please add an expounded version of this comment to the reply.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Done, but I've spent too much time on this already, I hope it's enough for you, because I don't have time to indulge this conversation any longer.  Good luck.